# Android application context param

Tags: java, android, this, android-context

I have a packed library .jar, and I want to access one class from it.
but in param this need `Context`, I am new in android dev). Tried to pass (`this`) on `MainActivity`, but result is `null`. Can you explain why is this happening and how to fix?

Here is sample code:

```
Context paramContext = this;
    ApiHttpClient localApiHttpClient = (ApiHttpClient)paramContext.getSystemService("com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient");
    if (localApiHttpClient == null)
      localApiHttpClient = (ApiHttpClient)paramContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService("com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient");
    if (localApiHttpClient == null)
        Log.d("loadState", "Result is null");
```

log:

```
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at com.example.dfgdf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:143)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4965)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at com.vine.android.vineApplication.getHttpUserAgent(Unknown Source)
06-04 10:57:44.502: E/AndroidRuntime(6610):     at com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient.(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is `this` there ? Activity ? simple class ?

Comment: Can we see a bit more? what is null? the context or ApiHttpClient?

Comment: yes, "MainActivity extends Activity", it's not loading ApiHttpClient load result is null, but not context.

Comment: Are you sure you have registered that service `com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient`?

Comment: registered ? i don't know how to register) but it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, may be you need add your JAR to ClassLoader and then make Class.forName like on Java do.

Here example

```
public static ClassLoader loadExternalJar(File file) throws Exception {
        if (file.exists()) {
            Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true);
            ClassLoader retClassLoader;

            retClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

            method.invoke(retClassLoader, new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
            return retClassLoader;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("File not found with JAR:"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

And then try call Class.forName("com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient")

Try this:

```
 try {
        Class<?> someApiClass = Class.forName("com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient");
        if (someApiClass != null) {
            ApiHttpClient localApiHttpClient = (ApiHttpClient) someApiClass
                    .newInstance();
            if (localApiHttpClient != null) {
                // TODO Oeprations
                Log.d("loadState", "Result is Good");
            } else {
                Log.d("loadState", "Result is null");
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: jar file is added as a library to eclipse, i can view all classes from it, but when load, result is null.

Comment: tryed Class.forName? What result? It can't be null. If Jar loaded as Library.

Comment: Class.forName("com.vine.api.ApiHttpClient") -> 06-04 10:46:13.582: W/dalvikvm(5935): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/vine/api/ApiHttpClient;

Comment: Edit answer, try code, what in log (and Exceptions try catch add)

Comment: So error in  at com.vine.android.vineApplication.getHttpUserAgent(Unknown Source), it's maybe what Constructor must be called with parameters. is it true?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31171/discussion-between-daniel-and-dmitry-nelepov)